# how to send nested functions data to another function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, function, nested-function

I want to display the value of a variable in world function.

````
def base():
    
    print("Hello World")
    
    def child():
        a = 10
        return a
    
def world():
    num = base.child() # error -------
    print(num)
    
world()```
````

Comment: What does `base` represent in the expressions `base.child()`? A scalar value, an object, a class, a method, or what?

Comment: base is a function

Comment: does a function have an attribute 'child'?

Comment: The base function have the child function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest calling child in base.

```
def base():
    
    print("Hello World")
    def child():
        a = 10
        return a
    return child()
def world():
    num = base()
    print(num)
    
world()
```

Comment: Now it's working, but I want another way (Don't return the child function from base function)

Comment: I don't think there's any way to access the inner function from outside. That's kind of the point. The best you can hope for is to access the _results_ of the inner function, exactly as @BuddyBob suggests. You might find this informative. [Python Inner Functions: What Are They Good For?](https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for)